# I have a problem with my mainloop in the background in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I am creating the snake game and I use the PyQt5 library for that. I'm doing well, however, I have a big problem in my main loop. The game is built like this: I create a grid that I fill with black QWidget. Then I change the color of the boxes to create the snake. To make it work, I have to create a function that updates the grid. It works without any problem because it is relatively simple. So, when I run the game in "manual", I don't have any problem, but when I run the game in my main loop, nothing works anymore. I really don't understand why because the same functions are called in both cases. It should give me the same result and yet not.

I'm going to put the two versions, the one I call "manual", that is to say that the events are triggered when the keys are pressed and then the normal version, that is to say with the main loop. The game is not finished, but without solving this problem, I would not succeed.

So here is the "manual" version, that is to say the test version:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys
from main import Snake
import time
from threading import Thread

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class SnakeGame(QWidget):
    """Cette classe est la partie graphique du
    jeu snake"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.obsolete = []
        self.running = True
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.cases = []
        super().__init__()
        self.create_window()
        self.mainloop = Thread(target=self.game_mainloop)

    def create_window(self):
        """Mise en forme de la fenetre et des tous ses composants"""
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(1)
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.setWindowTitle("Snake")
        self.resize(1080, 1080)

        for i in range(16):
            for a in range(16):
                case = QWidget()
                case.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;}")
                self.cases.append(case)
                self.grid.addWidget(case, i, a)

        self.snake.spawn()
        for i in self.snake.body:
            self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: red;}")

    def update_grid(self):
        """Cette fonction à pour objectif de mettre à jour la grille
        à chaque fois que elle est appelé"""

        for i in range(256):
            if i in self.snake.body:
                self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: red;}")
            else:
                self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;}")
        print("Update")


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.snake.add_case()
            self.update_grid()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Z:
            self.snake.direction = "Z"
            self.snake.avance()
            self.update_grid()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_S:
            self.snake.direction = "S"
            self.snake.avance()
            self.update_grid()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
            self.snake.direction = "Q"
            self.snake.avance()
            self.update_grid()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_D:
            self.snake.direction = "D"
            self.snake.avance()
            self.update_grid()

    def game_mainloop(self):
        while self.running:
            self.update_grid()
            time.sleep(1.0)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        self.running = False



game = SnakeGame()
game.show()


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The normal version, with the main loop:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys
from main import Snake
import time
from threading import Thread
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
class SnakeGame(QWidget):
    """Cette classe est la partie graphique du
    jeu snake"""
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.obsolete = []
        self.running = True
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.cases = []
        super().__init__()
        self.create_window()
        self.mainloop = Thread(target=self.game_mainloop)
 
    def create_window(self):
        """Mise en forme de la fenetre et des tous ses composants"""
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(1)
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(1)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
 
        self.setWindowTitle("Snake")
        self.resize(1080, 1080)
 
        for i in range(16):
            for a in range(16):
                case = QWidget()
                case.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;}")
                self.cases.append(case)
                self.grid.addWidget(case, i, a)
 
        self.snake.spawn()
        for i in self.snake.body:
            self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: red;}")
 
    def update_grid(self):
        """Cette fonction à pour objectif de mettre à jour la grille
        à chaque fois que elle est appelé"""
 
        for i in range(256):
            if i in self.snake.body:
                self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: red;}")
            else:
                self.cases[i].setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;}")
        print("Update")
 
 
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.snake.add_case()
            self.update_grid()
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Z:
            self.snake.direction = "Z"
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_S:
            self.snake.direction = "S"
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
            self.snake.direction = "Q"
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_D:
            self.snake.direction = "D"
 
    def game_mainloop(self):
        while self.running:
            self.snake.avance()
            self.update_grid()
            time.sleep(1.0)
 
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        self.running = False
 
 
 
game = SnakeGame()
game.mainloop.start()
game.show()
 
 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And finally, the Snake class which does not change:

```
import random
 
class Snake:
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.direction = "Z"
        self.body = []
 
    def spawn(self):
        """Cette fonction créer le corp du serpent"""
        self.body.clear()
        self.body.append(random.randint(0, 256))
        for i in range(2):
            self.add_case()
 
 
    def add_case(self):
        """Permet de faire grandir le serpent"""
        temp = random.randint(0, 3)
 
        if temp == 0:
            self.body.append(self.body[-1]+1)
        elif temp == 1:
            self.body.append(self.body[-1]-1)
        elif temp == 2:
            self.body.append(self.body[-1]+16)
        elif temp == 3:
            self.body.append(self.body[-1]-16)
 
        self.verification()
 
    def verification(self):
        """Cette fonction vérifie si la valeur ajouté dans le corp
        serpent est conforme ou pas. Si elle ne l'est pas, elle la supprime
        puis refais apelle à self.add_case"""
 
        if self.body[-1] not in range(256) or self.body[-1] in self.body[0:-1]:
            self.body.pop()
            self.add_case()
 
    def avance(self):
        temp = self.body[-1]
        if self.direction == "Z":
            self.haut()
        elif self.direction == "S":
            self.bas()
        elif self.direction == "D":
            self.droite()
        elif self.direction == "Q":
            self.gauche()
        return temp
 
    def haut(self):
        """Cette fonction fais avancer le serpent vers le haut dans la grille"""
 
        temp = self.body[0]
        self.body[0] -= 16
        for i in range(1, len(self.body)):
            self.body[i] , temp = temp, self.body[i]
 
    def bas(self):
        """Cette fonction fais avancer le serpent vers le bas dans la grille"""
 
        temp = self.body[0]
        self.body[0] += 16
        for i in range(1, len(self.body)):
            self.body[i], temp = temp, self.body[i]
 
    def gauche(self):
        """Cette fonction fais avancer le serpent vers la gauche dans la grille"""
 
        temp = self.body[0]
        self.body[0] -= 1
        for i in range(1, len(self.body)):
            self.body[i], temp = temp, self.body[i]
 
    def droite(self):
        """Cette fonction fais avancer le serpent vers la droite dans la grille"""
 
        temp = self.body[0]
        self.body[0] += 1
        for i in range(1, len(self.body)):
            self.body[i], temp = temp, self.body[i]
```

So, you will see, almost nothing changes between the two versions, except that the calling of functions is simply not done in the same way. I invite you to test it at home if you want to understand it better. I don't understand at all why this is the case, that's why I'm asking you.

Thank you in advance for your answers, have a nice evening.

Comment: `mainloop` does not return until the window closes, so you never get to your `show`.  What are you trying to accomplish by that?  You should be letting Qt's internal main loop do all of your dispatching.

Comment: Just use a QTimer and remove any infinite while loop as it prevents Qt to do **anything**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using `while True` loops and `time.sleep()` both freeze the GUI and the users ability to interact with the program.

What you can do instead is create a QTimer and connect to it's timeout signal, which is emitted and regular intervals, to your game_mainloop method, which then only needs to call the `snake.avance` and `update_grid` on each callback.

For example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer        # import QTimer

class SnakeGame(QWidget):
    """Cette classe est la partie graphique du
    jeu snake"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.obsolete = []
        self.running = True
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.cases = []
        super().__init__()
        self.create_window()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)  # create a QTimer object
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.game_mainloop)  # connect to timeout signal

    ...
    ...

    def game_mainloop(self):  # remove the sleep and while True loop
        self.snake.avance()
        self.update_grid()


game = SnakeGame()
game.show()
game.timer.start(1000)  # start a timer that will emit every second.
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your response, i tried with QTimer and it worked well.